# Rails multi-model form with data having a Hash containing a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hash

I'm faced with the following problem in rails. I have a form to edit/create a new project that may contain 1 to n sub-projects that again can contain 1 to n tasks.

So when I create a new project the controller executes:

```
@project = Project.new
sub_project = SubProject.new
work = Work.new
sub_project.works << work
@project.sub_projects << sub_project
```

Having the basic structure I generate the input fields in the view, the form I build up like this:

**Project**

```
<% form_for (:project, :url => action_parameter, :id => project) do |form| %>
```

**Subproject**

```
<% fields_for "project[sub_projects][]", sub_project do |subproject_form| %>
```

Up to here all went well but how do I now define the fields_for the tasks? The following attempt..

```
<% fields_for "project[sub_projects][works][]", work do |work_form| %>
```

.. is not the solution as I get the following error from Mongrel:

> Conflicting types for parameter
>   containers. Expected an instance of
>   Hash, but found an instance of Array.
>   This can be caused by passing Array
>   and Hash based paramters
>   qs[]=value&qs[key]=value.

Why doesn't this work? And how should I tackle my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a nested model form. Check out [this web cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) from Ryan Bates.

Comment: Hmm.. sadly the code I am working on is still Rails 1.2.3 and merging it to 2.x or even 3.x is at the moment still way out of my league..

Comment: after updating my application to 2.3.5 this was definitely the way to go. So thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why my code didn't work was that I forgot to add some extra braces in the work line..

```
<% fields_for "project[sub_projects][][works][]", work do |work_form| %>
```

However what I attempted to do does not seem possible with pre Rails 2.3.X. So I updated my App to that version and then used the nested forms which John Drummond suggested.